# FCM phone authentication not working in App Store Testing

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone Authenication for Login and Signup.

I have tested App with india numbers (+91) with around 20 phone numbers. OTP working for me.

When Uploading to Appstore. Apple reject my App Said OTP not Recieved.
seems OTP not working on USA (+1) numbers.
I am using Production mode.

```
[[FIRAuth auth] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeProd];
```

I have uploaded P.12 File on Firebase Console.

How can I solve this issue.?

Comment: are you using different configuration for development and production, if this is case make sure to reflect changes to production app on firebase too

Comment: @Van , I have already uploaded production certificates in Firebase Console.

Comment: okay, so the question is, are you using same configuration file for development as well as production mode. Is it?. Since in my case I used two different apps for development and production. so as per mode I will configure firebase in my AppDelegate. is it same in your case?

Comment: I have uploaded both Development and production Certificates in Firebase . OTP not recieved on  (+1) numbers..

Comment: is your OTP coming through notification? or SMS?

Comment: OTP coming Through SMS @Van

Comment: so for SMS what is connection with APNStoken? since apnstoken is for sending push notification, you might need to check with SMS gateway and not with Firebase, I believe

Comment: We need to enable push notification for SMS dear :) Have a look  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Comment: okay. sorry then , i have not worked with those feature yet. I thought your problem could be same as mine.

Comment: @Van did you find any solution?

Comment: No @Hossein my issue was different.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is likely happening is that the app store tester's phone number is getting rate limited. Firebase Auth allocates a specific quota per phone number to prevent abuse. If there are too many sign in attempts using the same phone number, Firebase Auth temporarily blocks them. The tester must be reviewing multiple apps using Firebase Auth phone number sign in and hitting the limit.

Firebase Auth team is working on a long term solution to fix this and facilitate testing.

For now, you could create a google voice phone number account and share it with the tester to ensure they don't hit the quota. You can also report this issue to Firebase Support: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: has anyone confirmed if this is actually the case?